# Is there any otherway to get configurable product and their options in Magento api

Tags: api, magento, magento-1.7

I'm using magento 1.7 and my problem is how to get configurable product and their options through a default api without creating a custom api. because my client wants to get the api's without modifying the actual source code on the server.

Now i can able to get the options like warranty & the screen protector but can't able to get a color and then a size. Please refer the attached screenshot below:

[image: configurable product and their options]

I have googled a lot more to find my solution without **writing a custom api** to get a configurable product. But so far no luck!

Is there any other way to get so? please let me know.

And please note, i'm a pure front end developer role. By referring the API reference documentation we are developing this application.

Referring the API document - http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $product->getOptions(), But make sure you load the product object $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

Comment: Sorry for the delay.i don't want to edit/modity the actual source code.is there any other way to get product options like color & size?

Comment: Referring the API document - http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: You need to create module for this, or use this code within your module. You dont need to modify core but have to extend it with your own module. Develop local module for your requirements.

Comment: Okay thats fine. But i don't have ftp access to add/modify modules.Now i have only the admin panel access.

Comment: Configurable products can be created with the ATTRIBUTES not with custom options. What your screenshot shows are the custom options. Custom option is basically taking user input for a product where attributes is like property of a product. Instead of using custom options you should create attributes for color and size and make them enabled to create configurable products(Which you can easily do from Attribute Edit screen).